# Store multiline EOSQL and with \ char query in variable and run it with psql

Tags: postgresql, bash, shell, psql

I have the following code in a shell script that initializes the `postgres` database in a `docker` container:

```
if [ "$ENV" == "development" ];
then
    psql --username "postgres" --dbname "postgres" <<EOSQL

    SELECT 'CREATE DATABASE $DATABASE' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_database WHERE datname = '$DATABASE');\gexec

    \connect "$DATABASE";

    DO \$\$
    BEGIN
        -- Some stuff
    END
    \$\$;

    -- Other stuff
EOSQL
else
    psql --host "$HOST" --username "postgres" --dbname "postgres" <<EOSQL

    SELECT 'CREATE DATABASE $DATABASE' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_database WHERE datname = '$DATABASE');\gexec

    \connect "$DATABASE";

    DO \$\$
    BEGIN
        -- Some stuff
    END
    \$\$;

    -- Other stuff
EOSQL
fi
```

In the `if` and `else` statement the SQL query is identical and I would like to put in a variable so I don't have to repeat it.

I tried to do `QUERY="..."`, then `psql ... -c "$QUERY"` but I get errors on the `\` char.

Is there a way to store this multiline SQL query in a variable and run it with `psql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always endeavor to avoid these cases and try to come up with a way around it if possible.  You could do it this way (and not change anything in your query code which works already!):

```
hostoption=""
if [[ "$ENV" != "development" ]]
then
    hostoption="--host $HOST"
fi

psql $hostoption --username "postgres" --dbname "postgres" <<EOSQL

SELECT 'CREATE DATABASE $DATABASE' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_database WHERE datname = '$DATABASE');\gexec

\connect "$DATABASE";

DO \$\$
BEGIN
    -- Some stuff
END
\$\$;

-- Other stuff
EOSQL
```

This way, `hostoption` is empty for development.  And adding a space after `psql` will not break anything.

For other environments, it contains the host option.

Answer (score 0):

To easily test your query, it's best to store it in a script and use `-f` from `psql`. But if you really need this query in the shell-script itself, you can use apostrophes to enclose your delimiter word (`EOF`) and inhibit shell expansion, than you can just copy-paste your tested sql-script into shell-script, like:

```
psql $hostoption --username "postgres" --dbname "postgres" <<'EOSQL'

SELECT 'CREATE DATABASE $DATABASE'  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_database WHERE datname = '$DATABASE');\gexec

\connect "$DATABASE";

DO $$
BEGIN
    -- Some stuff
END
$$;

-- Other stuff
EOSQL
```

A better programming logic for your question was already pointed out by @Nic3500.